# fullcalendar v2 resize not working

Tags: resize, fullcalendar

fullcalendar v2 if event show time the resize is not working 
example:  http://jsfiddle.net/949Xy/18/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
},
defaultDate: '2014-01-12',
editable: true,
events: [{
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: '2014-01-07',
    end: '2014-01-10'
},
{
    title: 'Long Event 2',
    start: '2014-01-07T00:30:00',
    end: '2014-01-09T08:30:00'
},
{
    title: 'Long Event 3',
    start: '2014-01-07T00:30:00',
    end: '2014-01-09T09:30:00'
}]
```

});

as you see long event3 can't resize but long event2 can resize.
it's may due to  long event3 show time and title.but long event2 only show title.
if i set long event3 like this 
title: 'Long Event 3',
start: '2014-01-07',
end: '2014-01-09'
long event3 can resize.

v1 don't have this problem

thank you for help

Comment: I think is the same problem than here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814568/fullcalendar-incorrect-event-end-date-after-eventresize/26884528#26884528

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the   `width: 900px;` from the `#calendar` class, it will work