# Moment.js internal object what is "_d" vs "_i"

Tags: momentjs

I am using Moment.js and manipulating a date using `moment.hour(xx)` `moment.minute(xx)`.

When i `console.log` the moment i see that the object contains a `_d` and `_i`:
the `_d` contains the correct changed `moment.hour()` or `moment.minute()` changes however the `_i` object contains the original?

```
k {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Thu Dec 11 2014 20:34:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time), _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: j…}
_d: Thu Dec 11 2014 14:00:00 GMT+0200
_i: Thu Dec 11 2014 20:34:00 GMT+0200
```

Could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Pay no attention to those.  Use the various output functions, such as `.format()` instead.  [See the Moment.js guidance on this topic](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/).  In short, all fields that are prefixed with an underscore (`_`) should be considered off limits.

The moment internals have some quirks due to how the `Date` object works.  All of the functions in the public API take them into account, but you probably don't want to figure them out yourself.

Just to be complete though, I'll elaborate on their purpose:

- `_i` is the *input* used when create the `moment` object.  It can be a string, a number, an array, or a `Date` object.

  However, if another `moment` object is passed in, the `_i` will be copied to that moments `_i`, and other properties will also be copied over.  `_i` will never be a `moment` object.

  `_i` can also be undefined, in the case of creating the current moment with `moment()`.
- `_d` is the instance of the `Date` object that backs the `moment` object.

  If you are in "local mode", then `_d` will have the same local date and time as the moment object exhibits with the public API.  The timestamps returned by `getTime` or `valueOf` will also match.

  If you are in "UTC mode", then `_d` will still have the same *UTC* date and time as the moment object exhibits with the public API.  This may be confusing, as you'd need to look at `getUTCDate` and other UTC-based functions on `_d` in order to see them match.  The timestamps will still match here as well.

  If you've changed the time zone offset, with the `utcOffset`, `zone`, or `tz` functions, then the `_d` value *cannot stand alone*.  It must also consider if `_offset` is defined.  If it is, then the timestamp backing the `_d` object has to first be adjusted by the amount of the offset.  You can see this behavior in the implementation of the `valueOf` method [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/7d121f205f070162a353e7f303490fd85ee31031/src/lib/moment/to-type.js#L1-L3).

  Also, if you look at the string output of `_d` when a different offset or time zone has been applied, it will *appear* that `_d` is using the *local* time zone.  However, that conversion to local time is simply a side effect of the `toString` function of the `Date` object.  Moment does not use that result in its functions.

This is the behavior for these two fields as of the current version (2.10.6 as I'm writing this).  However, there are other fields as well, and since these are *internal* fields, it's entirely possible the behavior could change in a future version.  In particular, see [issue #2616](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2617).

Comment: Great to know what the _I is.  Thought I had an issue as it was not changing when going forward or backwards months in my app.

Answer (score 5):

As a complement  to @Matt's answer:

Checkout this result from the chrome's console:

date1 is a moment's valid object:

[image]

As you can see, ._d and ._i have different values. So you better use the format() function (as @Matt Johnson wrote) inside your source code.