# how to update event start in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to update my db with the updated start date of an event I drag to a new day. I have a save button that runs the 'clientEvents' method to return all events to insert/update to the db. My problem is returning the correct event start date when an event that has been dragged to a new day.

I am doing this so far to update the event data:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, element) {

        event.title = "NEW TITLE!";
        event.start = event.start.format();
        event.color = "blue";

        console.log(event.start.format());
        console.log(event.start);
        console.log(event.start._i);
        console.log(event.title);
        console.log(event.color);

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event); //update the event data
    }
})
```

and my function to return all the events:

```
function saveEvents() {

    //get events array
    var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    console.log(events);
}
```

However, using this code, the title and color update fine but the start date will not update. Using console.log, the new title and color return correctly, but the start date is the original date, not the new date the event was dragged to. The same for the event data returned in my saveEvents function: the new title and color are correct, but not the start date.

The strange thing is, in the 3 ways I log the event.start, only the event.start.format() shows the correct new date. How do I get the new date saved so when a call 'clientEvents', the correct new data is returned?

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain what you mean by "original date" compared to what should be the "new date" ? Because you don't seem to update your start date as you only modify its format.

Comment: by using the clientEvents function, all event data is returned for each event on the calendar. The start date, end date, color, etc. When I drag an event to a new date on the calendar, and then run that function again, the start and end date/time has not been updated to the new date that I drug the event to.

Using eventDrop as shown above, I update an events color and start date when it is drug and dropped on a new date. Upon calling clientEvents, the new color is reflected, but the dates are not.

Comment: Hi, just giving you a heads up. In future you should not provide this kind of question to the original post as an answer. Instead you should comment below theirs until you feel you have enough information to give them a helpful answer. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Sorry for asking for information in an Answer @Chackle, given my low reputation i couldn't comment the original post... Back to the question : what version of FullCalendar do you use ? And in the 3 ways you log the event.start, do the 2 wrong ways log the old date ?

Comment: @CR It's alright. Just don't want your first experience of SO ending in you being down voted to oblivion with no understanding of why that happened.

Comment: I am using 2.3.1. The only way that logs the correct new date is event.start.format().  I have temporarily found a workaround by just deleting the original event and rendering a new one, but it just doesn't seem right I can't just simply update the old one.

Comment: It seems moment objects always keep track of their initial value... Your updated date can be accessed at event.state._d . But as said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126529/momentjs-internal-object-what-is-d-vs-i) it seems to be some Moment.js internal stuff. Hence there should be no issue when sending your event to DB. Have you already tried to do it ?

Comment: @CR event.state._d is not valid, did you mean event.start._d? either way, that still returned an empty value

Answer (score 0):

Create a moment copy of start, format it and attach to new event. Put your ajax call in the eventDrop callback in initialization of fullCalendar. Example solution using php and mysql:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, element) {
          var event_format = event;
          event_format.start = moment(event.start).format();
          $.ajax({
              url : "script.php",
              data : event=JSON.stringify(event_format),
              type : "POST"
          });

 }
})
```

php:

```
<?php
    $event = json_decode($_POST['event']);
    $query = "UPDATE x SET start = '$event->start'";
    mysql_query($query) or die ($query);
 ?>
```

Doing the same for the enddate would be a good idea :)