# Moment JS initialisation and the utc() method

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, utc

I would like to understand Moment JS' initialisation of its moment object.

For example, if I would like to create a moment for the date and time:
April 1 2000, 3:25:00 am with utc offset of +8 hours from UTC/GMT.

I represent this in a javascript object:

```
var obj = {
    year: 2000,
  month: 4, //APRIL
  day: 1,
  hour: 3,
  minute: 25,
  second: 0,
  utcOffset: 8  //8 hours from UTC
}
```

I then create a handy function I can use to create a moment with moment js:

```
var makemoment = function(obj){

  var m = moment([obj.year, obj.month - 1, obj.day, obj.hour, obj.minute, obj.second, 0]).utcOffset(obj.utcOffset);

  return m;
}
```

When I use this function to create moment...
e.g.

```
  var result =  moment(obj);
```

If I inspect the result object above I can see that it has a property `_d`
that I expect to have a value such as:

```
_d  Date {Sat Apr 01 2000 03:25:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)}
```

But the actual value is which for me does not make sense since I specified that the time is 3:25:00 and it is already at GMT +0800 so no need to add 8 hours to the time....

```
_d  Date {Sat Apr 01 2000 11:25:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)}
```

Despite of this _d value though, if I `console.log(result)`
I get the correct expected date:

```
2000-04-01T03:25:00+08:00
```

If I call the utc method on the moment. e.g. `result.utc()`
and if I inspect the object again, I can see that now the `_d` has changed to my originally expected value:

```
_d  Date {Sat Apr 01 2000 03:25:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)}
```

However, now if I do `result.format()`
I get the correct UTC date and time:

```
2000-03-31T19:25:00+00:00
```

Am I not understanding something here????
How is the _d value used in Moment.js???
Should I ignore the _d value since it is just something internal to Moment.js???

I've created JSFiddle for to illustrate my point...

http://jsfiddle.net/nx2ch4ot/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- It's a common convention in JavaScript that fields of an object that are prefixed by an underscore are meant to be treated as private/internal and not used directly.  Though it may be more user-friendly to hide them via closures, it's also slower, and thus libraries like moment.js choose to leave them exposed.
- Instead of using `_d`, call a public function such as `.format()`, or any of the others shown in the documentation.
- If you *really* want to know more about `_d`, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132227/634824).
- The time zone shown in a `Date` object will *always* be relative to the computer where the code is running.  JavaScript's `Date` object doesn't have the ability to reflect other time zones.  When moment uses `_d`, it mostly uses it just for its instantaneous value given by `_d.getTime()`, which reflects only UTC.  (We're actually considering removing `_d` entirely in a future version.)
- You do indeed need to adjust for the offset, but you should be starting from `moment.utc` instead of local time.  The corrected function is:

  ```
  var makemoment = function(obj){

    var m = moment.utc([obj.year, obj.month - 1, obj.day, obj.hour, obj.minute, obj.second, 0]);
    m.subtract(obj.utcOffset, 'hours');
    m.utcOffset(obj.utcOffset);

    return m;
  }
  ```
- The function you wrote is very similar to the one [already built in to moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/).  You can pass an object to either `moment` or `moment.utc`.  The difference with yours is that moment's uses zero-based months, and doesn't yet support passing a `utcOffset` field.  You might just consider using that instead.

  ```
  var makemoment = function(obj){

    obj.month--; // switch to zero-based months
    var m = moment.utc(obj);
    obj.month++; // put it back

    m.subtract(obj.utcOffset, 'hours');
    m.utcOffset(obj.utcOffset);

    return m;
  }
  ```