# Javascript Moment.js add a day to a date in milliseconds

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to add a day to a date in milliseconds.

The code I am using is bellow.

```
var x = 1450612800000;
var timeFrame = 'days'
x = moment(x).add(timeFrame, 1);
console.log(x['_i']) //returns 1450612800000
```

**Here is the fix:**

```
var x = 1450612800000;
var timeFrame = 'd'
var newDay = moment(x).add(tf, 1);

console.log('newDay');

//Get New Date in Milliseconds format
console.log(newDay.valueOf());

//Get New Date in Date Format
console.log(newDay.toDate());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132227/3692354

`_i` isn't what you want to use here - that's the input that was used to create the moment object. I think what you want to use instead is moment's valueOf function: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-offset/