# Converting moment UTC to Local date time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-format

I put a UTC .NET/JSON date from .net on client side. When I run the following command:

```
moment(value.Planet.when).utc()
```

The returned date from webservice:

```
"/Date(1469271646000)/"
```

I get a date in the _d parameter showing the current accurate UTC date with GMT+0300 on right side.

I want to convert this time to local time on the user machine and what ever I do, I always get the time 3 hours back.

I do this:

```
moment(value.Planet.when).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

and I get the same date time as the UTC. I don't understand how can I get momentjs to show the UTC time relative to the local time.  I checked that the momentjs object is indeed UTC.

I thought that if I pass the moment.utc() function the UTC date that I've got from the webservice (originally from the database), I can just run the local() function and I'll get the accurate hour relative to my area, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');

Eg:- if you date "/Date(1469271646000)/"

ip-> moment(1469271646000).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');

op-> "2016-07-23T16:30:46"

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `_d` property. It is for internal use only.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132227/634824), [the user guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/), or [Maggie's blog post on the subject](https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/).

As far as you question of how to convert to local time, you don't actually need to convert at all. You're already parsing the input value in local mode, so you can just use it directly:

```
var m = moment("/Date(1469271646000)/");  // gives you a moment object in local mode.
var s = m.format();   // lets you format it as a string.  Pass parameters if you like.
var d = m.toDate();   // gives you a Date object if you really need one
```

Try to avoid using `Date` objects unless they're required by some other controls or libraries you're using.  Most operations can be done strictly on `moment` objects.

Comment: I just put a new record and I get Sun Jul 24 2016 02:24:15 GMT+0300 if I use your code, but My local time is 5:24 not 2:24. The webservice returned "/Date(1469316255000)/" - so what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The timestamp `1469316255000` corresponds to `2016-07-23T23:24:15.000Z`.  You can check this in pure JS, or on many web sites, such as [epochconverter.com](http://www.epochconverter.com).  Your output shows three hours later because your local time zone offset for this value is `+03:00`.  If you're expecting it to be even three hours more than that, then I'd say your web service is sending out the wrong data.  Perhaps you are double-correcting.

Comment: For example, assuming your back-end is .NET, if you have UTC-based values in the database, but are not setting `DateTimeKind.Utc` when retrieving them (using `DateTime.SpecifyKind`), then they will have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` by default.  ASP.Net will consider those to be *local time* during serialization, and will subtract your server's local time zone offset.