# Why is moment.js giving different results when assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have been debugging this for a little while now and still haven't been able to figure it out. **Look specifically at the how the time in `_d` differs from the time in `_i`.  Why?**

```
var date = new Date('Fri, 06 Jan 2017 21:30:00 -0000')
const momentDate = moment(date)
console.log(`momentDate: `, momentDate);
console.log(`moment(date): `, moment(date));
```

[image]

Comment: One of the points of creating Moment.js was that parsing strings using the `Date` constructor is a Bad Idea(tm). Instead, use `moment(string, format)`, where the `format` provides how the library should parse the `string`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [momentjs internal object what is "\_d" vs "\_i"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126529/momentjs-internal-object-what-is-d-vs-i)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I actually started with that, but I got the same results.
[CODE / OUTPUT](http://imgur.com/a/BHxFk)

Comment: What "same results"? The question and its accepted answer provides information only. The real question is, who cares if these private variables differ at all? There's probably other code that's altering `momentDate` or something (maybe calling `startOf('day')`?), because when I run that code, I get two objects with the same values.

Comment: I also can't [reproduce](https://jsbin.com/vivitudofa/1/edit?html,js,output) the result from your screenshots. Try to reproduce it yourself on some online service.

Answer (score 1):

So what was causing the problem was I had a react component that was overwriting the values to `startOf('day')`.  If you're using moment to convert all your string dates flowing into your application into moment objects, if you experience bugs, make sure to look in your component and not just at the `convertToMoment` massaging functions for the API calls.

More importantly, until moment 3.0, all moment objects are mutable so if you do:

```
var a = moment()
var b = a.startOf('day')
console.log(a.format('LLL')) // January 22, 2017 12:00 AM
console.log(b.format('LLL')) // January 22, 2017 12:00 AM
```

The only way to fix this is either:

```
// use the cool `frozen-moment` package (which is basically a polyfill)
var a = moment().freeze()
var b = a.startOf('day')
console.log(a.format('LLL')) // January 22, 2017 2:17 AM
console.log(b.format('LLL')) // January 22, 2017 12:00 AM

// or type `.clone()` everytime you want to use a cool function
var a = moment()
var b = a.clone().startOf('day')
console.log(a.format('LLL')) // January 22, 2017 2:17 AM
console.log(b.format('LLL')) // January 22, 2017 12:00 AM
```