# fullcalendar getting the new start date of event after eventDrop

Tags: javascript, events, fullcalendar

I am having trouble getting the new start date of dragged and dropped event.

```
eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
    var droptodate = event.start.format(); // this will give you date where event is about to be dropped to
    droptodate1 = droptodate;

    var dropfromdate = event.start._i;  // this will give you date where event is from
    dropfromdate1 = dropfromdate;
},
```

the `droptodate` I get correctly but `from` still gives me old value from the day it initially came from.

I need both values to be in format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Can someone please tell me why from date is not updating?

Comment: I don't understand. You say "from still gives me old value from the day it initially came from." Then ask "why from date is not updating?". If `from` is giving you the previous date, then of course it won't "update". It will show the date as it was previously. However, you could also use the `delta` parameter to get the amount of time the event has moved by, and calculate the previous date using that. This appears to be the approved method, judging by the docs, instead of `_i` which is an internal property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126529/momentjs-internal-object-what-is-d-vs-i