# Moment.js wierd translation

Tags: momentjs

I'm using moment.js and getting something strange:

Input string:

```
'Wed, 30 Aug 2017 19:53:54 EST'
```

Want parse it using Moment.js:

```
moment('Wed, 30 Aug 2017 19:53:54 EST', 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z');
```

getting object:

```
_d: Wed May 31 2017 23:59:59 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time) {}
_f: "ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z"
_i: "Wed, 30 Aug 2017 19:53:54 EST"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
```

_i - it's input

_f - as I can understand - format

_d - it's date, result of parsing, WHY there 'May 31'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [momentjs internal object what is "\_d" vs "\_i"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126529/momentjs-internal-object-what-is-d-vs-i)

Answer (score 0):

Found and fixed problem. If someone faced with same problem, they could check my solution.
Datetime object mutate in controller:

```
let myDate = moment();
 ------------ skip ------------
let someObj = {
      yesterday: myDate.subtract(1, 'days')
    };
```

Because it's object, definitions like below doesn't helps:

```
const myDate = moment();
```

or

```
let myDate = moment();
Object.freeze(myDate);
```

only work solution for me is:

```
let myDate = moment();
 ------------ skip ------------
let someObj = {
      yesterday: myDate.clone().subtract(1, 'days')
    };
```