# Update Birthday using Year and Month values

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to display and update a child's age through a MM/dd/YYYY textbox, and simple int values in year(s) and month(s) textboxes.

So if a child had a birthday of: `02/03/2015`, and I'm comparing against today's date of `03/07/2018`, the Year textbox should say `3` and the month textbox should say `1`

If you were to change the year value to `5`, the DoB value should change to `02/03/2013`.
If you were to *then* change the month value to `9`, the DoB value should change to `05/03/2012`.
If I were to change the DoB value, the Year and Month textbox should also change to the appropriate values.
The day value should be persisted, and changed to `01` when it can't.

I would like to of course account for odd date arithmetic.

---

What I have so far in my C# MVC app is that I have a `ChildViewModel` object with these properties:

```cs
DateTime? DateOfBirth
public int AgeMonths
public int AgeYears
```

On my view, I have a textbox for each of these values.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Child's Date of Birth", onchange = "determineAge(this.id, null, null)" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AgeYears, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AgeYears, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "x years and...", onchange = "determineAge(null, this.id, null)" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AgeMonths, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AgeMonths, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "...y months old", onchange = "determineAge(null, null, this.id)" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript so far, slightly altered to work in the snippet, using a little bit of moment.js v2.21.0

https://jsfiddle.net/RyanTaite/fak22xrf
The snippet below is effectively the same code:

```js
function determineAge(dobId, ageYearsId, ageMonthsId) {
  ///<summary>Updates the Date of Birth, Years, and/or Months text box(es) based on what's passed in. It's likely terribly written and I'd welcome a rewrite by someone better at date math. Dependant on moment.js</summary>

  var dobValue = null;
  var yearValue = null;
  var monthValue = null;
  var today = new Date();

  // Update DOB, AgeYears, and AgeMonths based on who was changed
  if (dobId !== null) {
    dobValue = new Date(document.getElementById(DateOfBirth.value));
    var ageInMonths = today.getMonth() - dobValue.getMonth() + (12 * (today.getFullYear() - dobValue.getFullYear()));
    yearValue = Math.floor(ageInMonths / 12);
    monthValue = ageInMonths % 12;
    document.getElementById('AgeYears').value = yearValue;
    document.getElementById('AgeMonths').value = monthValue;
  } else if (ageYearsId !== null) {
    yearValue = document.getElementById('AgeYears').value;
    monthValue = document.getElementById('AgeMonths').value;
    dobValue = new Date(document.getElementById('DateOfBirth').value);
    dobValue.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - yearValue);
    document.getElementById('DateOfBirth').value = dobValue.toLocaleDateString();
  } else if (ageMonthsId !== null) {
    dobValue = new moment(new Date());
    monthValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('AgeMonths').value);
    yearValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('AgeYears').value);
    var dayValue = new moment(document.getElementById('DateOfBirth').value, "MMDDYYYY").get('date');
    var totalMonths = monthValue + (yearValue * 12);

    dobValue.subtract(totalMonths, "months");
    // This is the proper way to set the day value of a moment object, you have to chain your way there
    dobValue.year(dobValue.get('year')).month(dobValue.get('month')).date(dayValue);

    document.getElementById('DateOfBirth').value = moment(dobValue._d).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label">Date of Birth</div>
    <input class="form-control" id="DateOfBirth" placeholder="Child's Date of Birth" onchange="determineAge(this.id, null, null)"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label">Years</div>
    <input class="form-control" id="AgeYears" placeholder="x years and..." onchange="determineAge(null, this.id, null)"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label">Months</div>
    <input class="form-control" id="AgeMonths" placeholder="...y months old" onchange="determineAge(null, null, this.id)"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's buggy and likely terribly written, so I'd love some help with this.

Comment: This is way too broad.  You should focus on one problem at a time.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.  You should also consider using Moment's [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) and [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) functions instead of doing your own date math.  Also avoid using `_d`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Matt. I'll try to narrow this down further and I'll check out that `diff` function. Is there a reason to avoid using `_d`? Is it because there are better ways to get that information?

Comment: Yes.  Read [this](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132227/634824).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I fixed it using `diff` and general moment properties more, as [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson) comment suggested.

If nothing else, it's cleaner and closer to what I wanted.

I welcome anyone's suggestions or edits to improve this.

```js
function determineAge(dobId, ageYearsId, ageMonthsId) {
  ///<summary>Updates the Date of Birth, Years, and/or Months text box(es) based on what's passed in. Dependant on moment.js</summary>

  var dobValue = null;
  var yearValue = null;
  var monthValue = null;
  var today = new moment();

  // Update DOB, AgeYears, and AgeMonths based on who was changed
  if (dobId !== null) {

    dobValue = new moment(document.getElementById('DateOfBirth').value, "MMDDYYYY");
    yearValue = new moment().diff(dobValue, 'years');
    monthValue = new moment().diff(dobValue, 'month') % 12;

    document.getElementById('AgeYears').value = yearValue;
    document.getElementById('AgeMonths').value = monthValue;

  } else if (ageYearsId !== null || ageMonthsId !== null) {

    yearValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('AgeYears').value);
    monthValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('AgeMonths').value);
    dobValue = new moment(document.getElementById('DateOfBirth').value, "MMDDYYYY");
    
    const ageInMonths = (yearValue * 12) + (monthValue);
    const todayMinusMonths = today.subtract(ageInMonths, 'months');
    const dayValue = dobValue.date();
    dobValue = todayMinusMonths;
    dobValue.date(dayValue);

    document.getElementById('DateOfBirth').value = dobValue.format("MM/DD/YYYY");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label">Date of Birth</div>
    <input class="form-control" id="DateOfBirth" placeholder="MM/dd/YYYY" onchange="determineAge(this.id, null, null)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label">Years</div>
    <input class="form-control" id="AgeYears" placeholder="x years and..." onchange="determineAge(null, this.id, null)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label">Months</div>
    <input class="form-control" id="AgeMonths" placeholder="...y months old" onchange="determineAge(null, null, this.id)">
  </div>
</div>
```