# Moment JS date changes?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Could someone explain what happens here in this moment object that has been logged to the console? How does it become 17th October from the date passed when creating the moment object which was 21st October?

```
_d: Date 2018-10-17T00:00:00.000Z

_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"

_i: "2018-10-21T01:00:00+01:00"
```

Comment: All you need to provide is one line of code showing how you produced the moment object.

Comment: `_d`, `_f` and `_i` are [Internal Properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) and should not be used, I suggest to show your code to get further help.

Comment: Please do read [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs), especially the part about [Creation Data](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [momentjs internal object what is "\_d" vs "\_i"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126529/momentjs-internal-object-what-is-d-vs-i)