# How can I change a UTC moment.js object to reflect the "zone" property it already has?

Tags: datetime, timezone, momentjs, utc

Ok so I have this moment object I'm looking at in Developer Tools:

`amoment: Moment
_a: (7) [2017, 4, 21, 20, 15, 0, 0]
_d: Sun May 21 2017 15:15:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) {}
_f: "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A"
_i: "5/21/2017 8:15:00 PM"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", ordinal: ƒ, _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, …}
_offset: -180
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(1), overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 3, …}
_strict: false
_z: Zone {name: "America/Halifax", abbrs: Array(229), untils: Array(229), offsets: Array(229), population: 390000}
__proto__: Object`

As you can see, the text representation is 5/21/2017 8:15:00 pm. This is the correct time in UTC and I notice "_isUTC" is "true".

The _d property shows that datetime in CDT, where I am now.
The _z property shows a Zone object set to "America/Halifax"--this is dynamically set elsewhere, but also *correct*.

I would like to return a moment reading "5/21/2017 5:15:00 pm" because that's what that datetime is in "America/Halifax."

There are so many moment.js functions I haven't found the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All of the fields that begin with underscores (`_`) are meant to be internal to Moment.  You should not be using them at all.  More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28126529/634824), and [here](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/).

To output a string in a particular format from a `moment` object, use the [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) function.  For example:

```js
yourMomentObject.format("M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss a")  //=> "5/21/2017 5:17:00 pm"
```

Comment: Thanks... I was just using those as a reference because of the snippet I took from developer tools

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing `new Date(amoment.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00'));` which worked for my purposes. The zone kept wanting to render the date in that zone, so I just had to omit it.

Comment: That approach is not recommended.  If you want a `Date` object, use `.toDate()`, but understand that a `Date` object *cannot* represent the time in some arbitrary time zone.  The way you've got this here, you've chosen to have the `Date` object represent a very different point in time than the original `moment` object was.