# Can you set the time of your server different than your local machine?

Tags: node.js, time, server, timezone, momentjs

I am running into a problem with local debugging. I have a remote server which is set to UTC. My app is keeping daily running score and I calculate this score by taking all the values for a particular person passed a certain turn over date. For my app this is 1am CST or 6am UTC. The issue I'm running into is that if I have my local machine set to CST then the momentjs logic is messed up because the start of the day (1am) is calculated based off CST time instead of UTC time.

If I change my local machine's time to UTC then the front end logic no longer makes sense as I let the front end convert dates to whatever the local time of the user should be. Basically I need to simulate 2 servers working off different times. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Start of Day is calculated as follows:

```
const moment = require('moment');
module.exports = function getStartOfDay(){
        //set the start of the day to central standard time. It defaults to
        //UTC 0 otherwise;
        let now = moment();
        let cst = moment(now).subtract(6, 'hours');
        let midnight = moment(cst).startOf('day');
        let START_OF_DAY = moment(midnight).add(6, 'hours').utc();
        let START_OF_WEEK = moment(cst).startOf('week').add(6, 'hours').utc();
        let START_OF_MONTH = moment(cst).startOf('month').add(6, 'hours').utc();

        return {now, cst, midnight, START_OF_DAY, START_OF_WEEK, START_OF_MONTH}
};
```

first I get the actual moment,

then I subtract 6 hours to ensure that the correct day is calculated

then I get the start of that day, and finally add 6 hours back to it to compensate for the UTC offset

as you can see if I have my local machine running on CST time then the line:
`let now = moment();`
will be wrong

Comment: How are you deriving your start and end of day for the computation?

Comment: Not sure I follow, but why not do `let now = moment().utc()` ? wouldn't that solve your problem ?  Make all your computation using utc time that way ... It gives you a fixed framework for computation.  Did I understand your issue correctly ?

Comment: thank you turns out I can do that, though you have to do it in several operations, moment.utc() will not return the right time. I had to do this: let now = moment().utc(false).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss");
        let sod = moment(now).startOf('day');

Comment: Formatting and reparsing is generally discouraged, and you have a few bugs in that statement also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- Generally speaking, in any programming language, when one is intending code to run on a server, the code should be designed such that it does not depend on the time zone setting of that server.  You should get the same results regardless of where the code executes.  This means not using local-time functions.  Reserve those functions for code that executes on user's computer or device.  They usually have no purpose on a server, and lead to troubles such as the ones you are describing.
- In your code, you've set CST by subtracting 6 hours.  That's actually picking a different moment in time, rather than setting a time zone offset.  With Moment, you can change the time zone offset with the `utcOffset` function:

  ```
  let cst = moment().utcOffset(-6);
  ```
- While you've said `CST` in your question, consider that most places that observe Central Standard Time in the US and Canada switch between CST (UTC-6) and CDT (UTC-5) depending on if daylight saving time is in effect or not.  If you really mean CST, then use the `utcOffset` function like I showed above.  But if you actually meant Central Time, then you will need to install the [Moment-Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) extension, and use the `tz` function instead.  The time zone ID for CT in the USA is `America/Chicago`, so:

  ```
  let ct = moment.tz('America/Chicago');
  ```
- The rest of your code looks fine, though you may want to consider that Moment is a essentially a legacy project.  If you are writing new code that is intended to run on modern browsers and/or recent versions of Node.js, then the Moment team recommends you use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) instead.  Consider Luxon as if it were Moment 3.0, with a new API.  For example:

  ```
  const { DateTime } = require('luxon');
  let ct = DateTime.fromObject({zone: 'America/Chicago'});
  console.log(ct.toISO()); // "2018-11-01T12:31:10.140-05:00"
  ```

Comment: Thank you for such a great explanation. So since I want 1 am to be the turn overtime instead of midnight I use utcOffset(-6) instead of -5?

Comment: Changing the offset and changing the local time are two different operations.  If you want 1AM in UTC-6, then do `moment().utcOffset(-6).startOf('day').hour(1)`  or if you want something shorter, you can do `moment.parseZone('01:00-06:00', 'HH:mmZ')`.   However, if you want 1AM in Central Time (-6 or -5 depending on what is in effect), do `moment.tz('America/Chicago').startOf('day').hour(1)` or `moment.tz('01:00','HH:mm','America/Chicago')`.

Comment: The reason I use `hour(1)` instead of `add(1, 'hours')` is because not every day starts at midnight in every time zone.  Some time zones switch dst right at midnight advancing forward an hour, thus a day can start at 1AM already.  Not a concern for US Central time, but still a better habit to be explicit about the local hour.

Comment: so when I do utcOffset(-6).startOfDay() I get Oct 31 19:00 which doesn't make a lot of sense. Perhaps I'm understanding moment incorrectly. all my db dates are stored in UTC so if i have a date xDate (02:01:00 +000) and i ask moment if moment().utcOffset(-6).startOfDay().hour(1).isBefore(xDate) does it take the utc value of the offset time into account when it compares?

Comment: nevermind I found a blog post that explains why _d can show the wrong date

Comment: Indeed, always call a function like `format` to see output.  More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28126529/634824).