# Moment.js doesn't show correct time

Tags: momentjs, dst

When running my node.js project locally on my computer, moment.js is showing correct time (2019-10-28T07:00:00.000Z because moment have adjusted for DST +02:00 in april and +01:00 in october)):

```
Moment {
  _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: '2019-04-15T06:00:00.000Z',
  _f: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ',
  _tzm: 0,
  _isUTC: false,
  _pf:
   { empty: false,
     unusedTokens: [],
     unusedInput: [],
     overflow: -1,
     charsLeftOver: 0,
     nullInput: false,
     invalidMonth: null,
     invalidFormat: false,
     userInvalidated: false,
     iso: true,
     parsedDateParts: [ 2019, 3, 15, 6, 0, 0, 0 ],
     meridiem: undefined,
     rfc2822: false,
     weekdayMismatch: false },
  _locale:
   Locale {
     _calendar:
      { sameDay: '[Today at] LT',
        nextDay: '[Tomorrow at] LT',
        nextWeek: 'dddd [at] LT',
        lastDay: '[Yesterday at] LT',
        lastWeek: '[Last] dddd [at] LT',
        sameElse: 'L' },
     _longDateFormat:
      { LTS: 'h:mm:ss A',
        LT: 'h:mm A',
        L: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        LL: 'MMMM D, YYYY',
        LLL: 'MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A',
        LLLL: 'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY h:mm A' },
     _invalidDate: 'Invalid date',
     ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
     _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
     _relativeTime:
      { future: 'in %s',
        past: '%s ago',
        s: 'a few seconds',
        ss: '%d seconds',
        m: 'a minute',
        mm: '%d minutes',
        h: 'an hour',
        hh: '%d hours',
        d: 'a day',
        dd: '%d days',
        M: 'a month',
        MM: '%d months',
        y: 'a year',
        yy: '%d years' },
     _months:
      [ 'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December' ],
     _monthsShort:
      [ 'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec' ],
     _week: { dow: 0, doy: 6 },
     _weekdays:
      [ 'Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday' ],
     _weekdaysMin: [ 'Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa' ],
     _weekdaysShort: [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ],
     _meridiemParse: /[ap]\.?m?\.?/i,
     _abbr: 'en',
     _config:
      { calendar: [Object],
        longDateFormat: [Object],
        invalidDate: 'Invalid date',
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/,
        relativeTime: [Object],
        months: [Array],
        monthsShort: [Array],
        week: [Object],
        weekdays: [Array],
        weekdaysMin: [Array],
        weekdaysShort: [Array],
        meridiemParse: /[ap]\.?m?\.?/i,
        abbr: 'en' },
     _dayOfMonthOrdinalParseLenient: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/ },
  _a: [ 2019, 3, 15, 6, 0, 0, 0 ],
  _d: 2019-10-28T07:00:00.000Z,
  _isValid: true,
  _z: null }
```

But on my server, I get this:

```
Moment {
  _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: '2019-04-15T06:00:00.000Z',
  _f: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ',
     week: [Object],
     weekdays: [Array],
     weekdaysMin: [Array],
     weekdaysShort: [Array],
     meridiemParse: /[ap]\.?m?\.?/i,
     abbr: 'en' },
  _dayOfMonthOrdinalParseLenient: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/ },
  _a: [ 2019, 3, 15, 6, 0, 0, 0 ],
  _d: 2019-10-28T06:00:00.000Z,
  _isValid: true,
  _z: null }
```

The date is incorrectly set to 2019-10-28T06:00:00:000Z.
I have set the timezone on the server with `sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Oslo`

If I am using `moment.isDST()` for dates on the server, it correctly gives my `true` in April and `false` in October.

I am unsure how to solve this, on the server or in my code?

Comment: What was the original date? Also, you meant "-1 in october", right?

Comment: The original date was 2019-04-15T06:00:00.000Z entered in April, with time UTC +02:00 and DST. In October we don't have DST in Oslo, so the correct time shown in October will be 2019-10-28T07:00:00.000Z because we have UTC +01:00

Comment: Let's see if I understood your problem correctly. You're creating moment object with `2019-04-15T06:00:00.000Z`, in your local timezone it should be `2019-04-15T08:00:00.000 UTC+02:00` and that's correct. After adding to this date, for example, `6 months`, it should be (in your local timezone): `2019-10-15T07:00:00.000 UTC+01:00`, but it isn't?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. My local desktop computer running the node.js does this correctly, but not my Linux server

Comment: And what exactly is the datetime in your local timezone (in october) then? What is the output of`dt.toLocaleString()`?

Comment: 2019-10-28T06:00:00.000Z (DST ends 2019-10-27, so I will use the 28th here, not 15th) and in local time this will be 2019-10-28T07:00:000 UTC+01:00

Comment: What _is_ the output of command I mentioned above for october date?

Comment: My local desktop computer gives me: Mon Oct 28 2019 08:00:00 GMT+0100, and my server gives me: Mon Oct 28 2019 06:00:00 GMT+0000

Comment: Here is your problem. Your server thinks that its local timezone is UTC.

Comment: But if I run timedatectl on my server, I get:                       Local time: Wed 2019-04-17 10:31:28 CEST
                  Universal time: Wed 2019-04-17 08:31:28 UTC
                        RTC time: Wed 2019-04-17 08:31:29
                       Time zone: Europe/Oslo (CEST, +0200)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no

Comment: Doesn't moment obtain timezone from the computer it runs on?

Comment: What is the output of `moment().utcOffset()`?

Comment: My local computer gives me: 60, and the server 0 for the dates in October

Comment: Hi.  Please read about [Internal Properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) in the Moment.js user guide, and in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126529/momentjs-internal-object-what-is-d-vs-i).  (Pasting internal properties here does not help us understand your question.)

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it. By answering the from Styx questions, I finally realized that the server  app running in a docker container didn't have the correct timezone. By setting `environment: TZ: "Europe/Oslo"` in the `docker-compose.yml` file this fixed the problem, and I am getting correct time now.

Comment: Generally speaking, one should not design server-side applications such that they rely on a specific local time zone.  Though this may resolve the problem you have at the moment, it doesn't set you up well for success going forward.  Consider if your application ever needs to support users from a second time zone, or more.  You'll have painted yourself in a corner, so to speak.