# How to change the timezone of the date object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, momentjs

I am using moment to set/change the timezone of my date object and not any other date/time value

This is what I am presently doing :

```
const moment = require("moment-timezone");
const dateNew = moment.tz(accountDate, "US/Pacific");
```

This is the accountDate value: `Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

I want to change it to: `Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`

but the `dateNew` is still in EDT timezone.

```
the output of `console.log(dateNew)` is :


Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), _isUTC: true, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d: Sun Jul 07 2019 23:05:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
_i: Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", ordinal: ƒ, _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, …}
_offset: -420
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
_z: Zone {name: "US/Pacific", abbrs: Array(186), untils: Array(186), offsets: Array(186), population: 15000000}
__proto__: Object
```

but `console.log(new Date(dateNew))` gives the following output.

```
Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are indeed changing the timezone, everything is working fine, just add a format(), I don't have enough reputation to comment this yet, lol, but why are you using Date(), just stick to moment()

```
 const dateNew = moment.tz(accountDate, "US/Pacific").format();
 console.log(dateNew)
```

Comment: The thing is that I would just stop using new Date() altogether, the date is correct but you can't play with timezones that easily with Date(), that's why I suggest you only use moment(). This might explain it a bit better:

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126529/momentjs-internal-object-what-is-d-vs-i

And a cheat sheet to display the date however you want with moment:

https://devhints.io/moment

Comment: It is converting the entire date object with moment too. can you share a code snippet on what you are suggesting. Thanks

Comment: Sure, so this would work for your code to get the exact output you want:

const accountDate = 'Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'

const dateNew = moment(accountDate).tz('US/Pacific')

console.log(dateNew.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ'))

OUTPUT: Mon Jul 08 2019 03:05:22 GMT-0700

Comment: [GMT] between square brackets is just adding a string of your choice to the output

Answer (score 0):

Since you included reactjs tag. I will give you an answer in react.js way. You could install npm package named `moment-timezone` to solve this. Please take a look in their [docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) as well. Here is a full example in React

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import moment from "moment-timezone";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const _date = "Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)";
    const result = moment.tz(_date, "US/Pacific");
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Origin Date : {_date}</p>
        <p>
          Converted Date : {result.format()} {result.tz()}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The above code will results like this

[image]

Comment: I do not want to change the date object just the time zone. I want the Converted Date to be : Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting it as another answer so I can add it as code @Tanu

```
const accountDate = 'Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)' 
const dateNew = moment(accountDate).tz('US/Pacific') 
console.log(dateNew.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ zz')) 


//OUTPUT: Mon Jul 08 2019 03:05:22 GMT-0700 PDT
```

Additionally, you can add change the abbreviations like this and add a parenthesis with some other square brackets:

```
var abbrs = {
    EST : 'Eastern Standard Time',
    EDT : 'Eastern Daylight Time',
    CST : 'Central Standard Time',
    CDT : 'Central Daylight Time',
    MST : 'Mountain Standard Time',
    MDT : 'Mountain Daylight Time',
    PST : 'Pacific Standard Time',
    PDT : 'Pacific Daylight Time',
};

moment.fn.zoneName = function () {
    var abbr = this.zoneAbbr();
    return abbrs[abbr] || abbr;
}
```

So the output would now bew:

```
console.log(dateNew.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ [(]zz[)]')) 

Mon Jul 08 2019 03:05:22 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Comment: Hey Sdpotts93 I do not want to convert the date. I want the output to be Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0700 PDT. Thanks

From the question I posted :
This is the accountDate value: Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

I want to change it to: Mon Jul 08 2019 06:05:22 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)