# Array Push 'Different Info' Results in Pushing Same First Iteration For Every Iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, momentjs, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I am trying to notify user about his medication 3 times daily So I created:

```js
let timesPerDay = []

const today = moment();
//not working
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  timesPerDay.push(today.add(8 * i, "hour"));
}
//working normally
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(today.add(8 * i, "hour"));
}

console.log(timesPerDay)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

But there is a weird bug that when pushing to array it **saves** the **first date for every iteration** not adding 8 hours to it every time, that's so weird!

How Array.push is working?

Is JavaScript too fast in creating the array so the first loop is not working but the second is working?

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/microsmsm-the-flexboxer/pen/BaypYVO

Edit:

Same Snipped I am using after answers is not working

https://codepen.io/microsmsm-the-flexboxer/pen/KKwaoeM

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's absolutely not _"weird"_. It's working as expected because [`.add()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) _"mutates the original moment by adding time."_

Comment: @Andreas but I am adding 0 hours at first iteration 8 at second iteration and 16 at last iteration why the array is resulting in same value?

Comment: I expect all dates to be equal actually, the value of the last mutation. Every iteration is mutating the same instance

Comment: but why second loop working normally?

Comment: The second loop appears to work normally as it output at each interval instead of at the end. It should still be startdate +0 at first + 0 + 8 at second and + 0 + 8 + 16 at the end

Comment: You're adding `0+8+16+0+8+16` hours to the initial value of `today`. After the loop `today` should be two days in the future.

Comment: Is JavaScript too fast in creating the array so the first loop is not working but the second is working?

Comment: How Array.push is working?

Comment: It's mutating the same value in first loop but has different behaviour working normally in second loop

Comment: the second loop isn't "working"... console.log is calling the to string method of the moment object AT THAT POINT IN TIME to log. you're still mutating the same object over and over but it's not affecting past logged string representations of the object. if you were calling `timesPerDay.push(today.add(8 * i, "hour").toString());` on each iteration, you'd see the same results in the first loop.

Comment: Here is what you get if you output it on the loops:
today: Wed Dec 18 2019 17:03:02 GMT+0100
Loop 0: Wed Dec 18 2019 17:03:02 GMT+0100
Loop 1: Thu Dec 19 2019 01:03:02 GMT+0100
Loop 2: Thu Dec 19 2019 17:03:02 GMT+0100.
It "appears" to be correct. But if you actually count the offset, you notice it isn't.

Comment: I still don't get it :(

Comment: Still not working after I cloned new object:
https://codepen.io/microsmsm-the-flexboxer/pen/KKwaoeM

Comment: Your result is correct now. Focus on the string output instead of the properties of the object. You can get the string representation by .toString() or .format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

walking you through your code step by step:

```
let timesPerDay = [] // create an array

const today = moment(); // create a moment object

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // add hours to moment object
  // push a reference to that moment object into your array
  // it's always a reference to the SAME moment object, so the same object is referenced in your array multiple times
  // mutations to that object will show everywhere it is referenced
  timesPerDay.push(today.add(8 * i, "hour")); 
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // add hours to same moment object
  // log the string representation of that object AT EACH ITERATION
  // once transformed to a string, the string representation will not change as it is no longer part of the object
  console.log(today.add(8 * i, "hour"));
}

console.log(timesPerDay) // log string representation of your array, which is just 3 references to the same object
```

Comment: is console.log breaking the refrence as it's sync log second after another?

Comment: console.log calls toString to transform the object to a string that can be logged. that string is output from a function on the object, its not the object you're mutating anymore

Comment: So how can I solve the problem by making 3 different values in the array?

Comment: create a new moment object at every iteration

Comment: I tried but still the same problem, please check screen shot

Comment: it's working exactly as expected in that codepen. I'm not sure what you're after if it's not that

Comment: I think he is focussing on the _i property, which is the input date of his moment, which is the same in his code (as expected). He isn't using the .format or .toString to determine whether its right or wrong...

Answer (score 1):

this happens because you use same moment object to push
So this should help

```js
let timesPerDay = []

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  timesPerDay.push(moment().add(8*i,"hour"));
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(moment().add(8*i,"hour"));
}

console.log(timesPerDay)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but why it's working normally in the second loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since momentjs `.add` is mutating the `today` variable, all dates will be the same (equal to the the starting date + 0 + 8 + 16 hours) because you are pushing the same reference all the time.

You have to clone the date to start fresh.

```
const today = moment()
console.log(`Today: ${today}`)
// Today: Wed Dec 18 2019 17:14:11 GMT+0100
// Loop 0: Wed Dec 18 2019 17:14:11 GMT+0100
// Loop 1: Thu Dec 19 2019 01:14:11 GMT+0100
// Loop 2: Thu Dec 19 2019 09:14:11 GMT+0100
const times = [0, 1, 2].map(offset => {
    const date = moment(today) // clone
    date.add(8*offset,"hour")
    console.log(`Loop ${offset}: ${date}`)
    return date
})
```

Edit: not + 8 + 16 + 24 but 0 + 8 + 16

Edit 2: Proof that the second iteration with the console.log is not outputting what OP wants:

```
let timesPerDay = []

const today = moment();
console.log(`today: ${today}`)

// today: Wed Dec 18 2019 17:03:02 GMT+0100
// Loop 0: Wed Dec 18 2019 17:03:02 GMT+0100
// Loop 1: Thu Dec 19 2019 01:03:02 GMT+0100
// Loop 2: Thu Dec 19 2019 17:03:02 GMT+0100
// Last loop is 24 hours later than the initial date!
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // Mutates your start date
   const newDate = today.add(8*i,"hour");
   timesPerDay.push(newDate);
   console.log(`Loop ${i}: ${newDate}`);
}

console.log(timesPerDay)
```

Comment: The answer is not working for me I tried "cloning the object" but still have same results in array

Comment: The answer is working. I've added the same console logging as the 'proof'. The screenshot provided is code which differs from my answer. Update your snippet instead of a screenshot.

Comment: It is the result that you want, no? If you stringify the date, you get what you expected. I think you are focussing on the _i property which is the initial date, whilest the _d property is the modified one. What the _i and _d do, is beyond me, but when you stringify the dates, the correct output is generated.

Comment: Clarification of _i and _id can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126529/momentjs-internal-object-what-is-d-vs-i)